# Send file over ftp data channel

Tags: c#, file, ftp

I'm writing my own FTP server on C#. All is working good so far.
Now, as FTP needs, it uses an seconds channel for data connections. There it sends the file list, sends a/more file/s and it accepts files.
As the file list is working, I'm now experiencing problems downloading files.
Several FTP clients only receive and saves some bytes. When I got a file storing Loggings, it will only fetch the first characters of the first line. So, raw data isn't working at all.
P.S.: Before **RETR** a file, the client asks for **SIZE**, which the server answers.

I have this peace of code to send a file using the data connection.

```
public void SendFile(String strFilename) {
    if(!m_bConnected) 
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection on DataConnection");

    while(!m_bConnected) {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    } // while end

    byte[] btFileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(strFilename);
    int iContentLen = btFileContent.Length;
    sw.Write(btFileContent, 0, iContentLen);
    sw.Close();
}
```

I did some internet research. Has this something to do with the BINARY/ASCII mode? Are there some other rules I have to look, when sending files to the FTP client? Do you have some idea about how to solve this problem?

Thank you for now,

DeZio

Comment: Apart from needing to go into BINARY mode nothing seems wrong with this. However, you don't really need to read the input file in memory. Look into copying from a `FileStream` (in .NET 4 there is a handy `CopyTo` metho that makes it an one-liner).

Comment: How about transferring large files (larger than your ram), would your solution work for that?